# How do I create a UISlider dynamically in code?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I would like to know how to create a UISlider at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add a slider like ever other view:

```
UISlider *slider = [[[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 100, 40)] autorelease];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(controlValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
slider.minimumValue = 100.00;
slider.maximumValue = 1000.00;
slider.continuous = YES;
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

Use a frame that suits your needs, and add to the appropriate view (I used self.view in this example). Feel free to configure as needed. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(50, 170, 205, kSliderHeight);
customSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[customSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
customSlider.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIImage *stetchLeftTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellowslide.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
UIImage *stetchRightTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"orangeslide.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
[customSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"slider_ball.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchLeftTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchRightTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```